# Bing Desktop daily wallpaper not updating

Tags: windows-7, laptop

How do I get the daily Bing desktop to update the wallpaper? It worked fine for months, but now it has stopped updating. I am looking at the same wallpaper image now for weeks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bing Desktop not updating the wallpaper anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/799724/bing-desktop-not-updating-the-wallpaper-anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the standard "Windows" answer, but it comes from my own experience. I had the same thing happen to me. Try uninstalling it and reinstalling the bing stuff. It fixed the problem for me.